# Instantiate class in the constructor rather in the top end?

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

Is there a way to define class variables in the constructor or in a method rather than at the top of the document?

I have the following code in my custom library:

```
#include "DHT.h"

// DHT settings.
#define DHTPIN 7 // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor.
#define DHTTYPE DHT22 // DHT 22 (AM2302), AM2321
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); // Initialize DHT sensor.

void DhtLib::doSomeStuff() {
  dht.begin();
  float temp = dht.readTemperature();
  ...
}
```

I would like to be able to set the pins with a function. But for this to work I have to find a way to define the `dht` variable in a different place than at the top of the document within the `// DHT settings.`. Best would be in a method such as:

```
void DhtLib::begin(int dhtPin) {
  DHT dht(dhtPin, DHTTYPE);
}
```

This works, but only within this function. I need this to be accessible in the entire document, not just a single function.

How can I achieve that?

**EDIT 1:**

Entire code of the custom DhtLibrary.h file:

```
#ifndef DhtLibrary_h
#define DhtLibrary_h

#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
  #include "Arduino.h"
#else
  #include "WProgram.h"
#endif

class DhtLib {
  private:
    DHT dht;
    float readTemperatureFromDHT();
    float readHumidityFromDHT();
    float calculateHeatIndex(float temperature, float humidity);
    
  public:
    // Constructor.
    DhtLib(int dhtPin) : dht(dhtPin, DHT22) {}

    // Methods.
    void begin();
    String getHumiTempJson();
};

#endif
```

The error with this above code is:

```
In file included from /home/myuser/Documents/Codes/temperature-control/slave2-arduino/slave2-arduino.ino:2:0:
DhtLibrary.h:12:5: error: 'DHT' does not name a type
     DHT dht;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's numerous ways of doing this. The best is probably to have a DHT object as a class property and set it up with an *initializer list*:

```
#include "DHT.h"

class DhtLib {
    private:
        DHT dht;

    public:
        DhtLib(int dhtPin) : dht(dhtPin, DHT22) {}
        void begin();
        void doSomeStuff();
};

void DhtLib::begin() {
    dht.begin();
}

void DhtLib::doSomeStuff() {
    float temp = dht.readTemperature();
}

DhtLib thing(7);

void setup() {
    thing.begin();
}

void loop() {
    thing.doSomeStuff();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Can you please elaborate the part `DhtLib(int dhtPin) : dht(dhtPin, DHT22) {}`? I don't quite understand the parts of what it does exactly. Is that still a constructor definition? And don't I have to also declare the `DHT dht;` from the `DhtLibrary.h` in the `DhtLibrary.cpp` file?

Comment: That is the "initializer list". Yes it's the constructor. When you construct it passes the variables up to the DHT object you set up in the `private` section. The `DHT dht` is declared inside the DhtLib class.

Comment: Ok, got it. Well, if I place the `DHT dht;` in the `private:` section the compiler is unhappy, giving the error `DhtLibrary.h:20:5: error: 'DHT' does not name a type`. It expects `DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);`.

Comment: Which library are you using? The one I have here works fine.

Comment: I use the `DHT sensor library` by Adafruit Version 1.3.10.. Which one are you using?

Comment: Can you link to it?

Comment: Well, the `More info` link points to this url: https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library

Comment: Compiles fine for me with that library.

Comment: I don't quite get where I would do the error. I put my entire code into the `EDIT 1` in my post above. Do you see any error with that?

Comment: You have to include the DHT.h library in your header so it knows what a DHT is.

Comment: You said that you use another library for the DHT. Which one is it? Is there any particular reason you use a different library for the DHT?

Comment: I just happened to have the Grove library on hand that uses DHT.h for the header name, so I just used it. No other reason.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info and for your help!

Comment: Say I had another variable that I wanted to take, i.e. `DhtLib(int dhtPin, int anotherVariable) : dht(dhtPin, DHT22) {}`, how could I make use of it? Having defined `private: int privateVariable;` in the `DhtLibrary.h` I tried `DhtLib(int dhtPin, int anotherVariable) : dht(dhtPin, DHT22) {privateVariable = anotherVariable}`, but I get the error `error: 'privateVariable' was not declared in this scope`. How can I set `privateVariable` with `anotherVariable`?

Comment: You would usually just add it to the initializer list: `DhtLib(int dhtPin, int anotherVariable) : dht(dhtPin, DHT22), privateVariable(anotherVariable) {}`

Comment: Ok, so what are the curled-braces for? Is it possible to put logic into them?

Comment: Yes, that's just an empty function body where you would put the code for the constructor if you should ever want any.

Comment: Do you have any link for a description to this particular syntax?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've been a great help!